# Passing list to array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a list of indices which are `index= np.array([4,2,3,1])`. I have a two dimensional array `blah` and would like to extract the rows of `blah` using `blah[index,:]`. I know you can do this in R, but how do you do this in python/numpy?

Comment: Doesn't `blah[index, ]` give you what you want? (Same syntax as in R)

Comment: I get an IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type. I am not sure what this means

Comment: Please post a reproducible example- your `index` must not be what it looks like here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [24]: index = np.array([4,2,3,1])

In [25]: blah = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]])

In [26]: blah[index]
Out[26]:
array([[5],
       [3],
       [4],
       [2]])
```

Comment: I get an IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type. I am not sure what this means

Comment: What is your `index.dtype`? Your `index` is not `np.array([4,2,3,1])`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that with a two dimensional array "blah", you can do the following:

```
index= np.array([4,2,3,1])
blah=np.array([[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]])
matrix=[]
for i in range(len(blah)):
    matrix.append(blah[i][index])

print np.array(matrix)
```

result:

```
[[ 5  3  4  2]
 [10  8  9  7]]
```